# How to insert document in MongoDB by keeping a field (eg : 'name') as unique . In node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi is there a method to insert the document into Mongo DB keeping name(in my data) as unique. It works fine with a find and an update method. Is there a way to do it a single Query.

I have tried update operation but it doesn't work

```
 let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27020/mydb', (connectError, db) => {
    if (connectError) {
        console.log(connectError);
        return;
    }
    db.collection('products').update({name: {$ne :data.name}}, (updateError, updateData) => {

       db.close();
        if (updateError) {
         console.log(updateError);
            return;
        }

       console.log(updateData)
       });

   });
```

Comment: create a unique index on name field in DB. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-on-a-single-field

Answer (score 0):

You should [create a unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/).

Beware that

> MongoDB cannot create a unique index on the specified index field(s) if the collection already contains data that would violate the unique constraint for the index.